# Custom linked binary has LOAD segment with RWX permissions

Tags: linker, kernel

I have a custom linker script for my binary:

```
ENTRY(kmain)
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)

SECTIONS {
    . = 0xFFFFFFFF80000000;

    .text ALIGN(4K) : { *(.text) }

    .rodata ALIGN(4K) : { *(.rodata) }
    
    .data ALIGN(4K) : { *(.data) }

    .bss ALIGN(4K) : { *(.bss) }

    .eh_frame ALIGN(4K) : { *(.eh_frame) }
}
```

This linker script produces these section headers:

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS         ffffffff80000000  000000c0
       0000000000009b2e  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     16
  [ 2] .rodata           PROGBITS         ffffffff8000a000  0000a0c0
       0000000000001297  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [ 3] .data             PROGBITS         ffffffff8000c000  0000c0c0
       0000000000000ab1  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     32
  [ 4] .bss              NOBITS           ffffffff8000d000  0000cb71
       00000000000088b3  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     32
  [ 5] .eh_frame         PROGBITS         ffffffff80016000  0000cb78
       00000000000015d4  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
```

Which appears to be correctly page aligned, like I specified in the linker script. However, the .text -> .bss sections end up in a single LOAD segment with RWX permissions. This produces a warning in newer versions of gcc. Interestingly only .eh_frame gets its own LOAD segment:

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  LOAD           0x00000000000000c0 0xffffffff80000000 0xffffffff80000000
                 0x000000000000cab1 0x00000000000158b3  RWE    0x20
  LOAD           0x000000000000cb78 0xffffffff80016000 0xffffffff80016000
                 0x00000000000015d4 0x00000000000015d4  R      0x8
```

This is an issue because when I load the binary into memory I would like to set the page table permissions correctly. I.e. no execute in .data and no write in .text. How can I change my linker file to produce a load segment for each section with unique permissions?

I tried changing the alignments and orders of my linker script to no avail.

Comment: Which linker did you use? `bfd`, `gold`, `lld`, `mold`? Does the answer change when you switch between them? Assuming you used `bfd`, does adding `-z separate-code` change things?

Comment: @EmployedRussian I am using the GNU linker `ld`. Sorry, I'm not too familiar with other linkers. But I added -z separate-code which still produces only RWX segments

Answer (score 0):

which ld version do you use?
maybe you need use a newer version that contain this patch.
https://marc.info/?l=binutils-cvs&m=151976136124015&w=2

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).